# webclient Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to use the DownloadFile function of webclient but I used breakpoint to see which line O got error. It just go to catch block when DownloadFile.

```
            try
            {
                string myStringWebSource = this.curFtpIp + FtpCuPath + "/" + FtpdfName + "/" + this.lbl.Text;

                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.FtpUserID, this.FtpPassword);
                client.DownloadFile(myStringWebSource, SaveFile);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
            finally { }
```

Comment: WHAT KIND OF ERROR FACED ??????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my own question. I found that I set the wrong second parameter. I just use "SaveFile" which is save path but it should be a file name. So, I just modified the SaveFile and it can work.

[WebClient.DownloadFile MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/ez801hhe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)